# Is there a way to reference a list of mobile workers as possible choices for a multichoice questions in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

I would like to have a checkbox or single select question in CommCare that is a list of possible answer choices Is there a way to directly reference a list of mobile workers in order to populate a list of possible answer choices with mobile worker names?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible in CommCare. I think your best bet would be to use a [Lookup Table](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Lookup+Tables).

Answer (score 0):

This may be slightly unconventional—and I haven't tried it myself—but I can't think of a reason it wouldn't work.

If you set up user-as-a-case then you'll have one case per user. You can then assign these user-cases to case sharing groups using a case import. This is necessary in order for you to configure which user-cases end up on which users' phones. (The default is for each user to only get their own user-case.)

Finally, if the above setup works, then you can configure the multiple choice question to pull its answers from the list of user-cases following https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Multiple+Choice+Questions+with+Cases+as+Choices.

(Please upvote/accept if it works and comment if it doesn't. I can the update the answer to reflect your findings.)

Comment: I'll give this a shot and accept if it works! thanks!